# Assign to list index in specific environment using `get`

Tags: r

If I make an environment with a list in it, and want to assign values to that list, why does the following fail when using `get` and `assign`?

```
res <- new.env()
res$calls <- vector("list", 100)
res$counter <- 1

## works fine
res$calls[[1]] <- 1

## Fails, why?
get("calls", envir=res)[[get("counter", envir=res)]] <- 2

## doesnt make the assignment
val <- get("calls", envir=res)[[get("counter", envir=res)]]
assign("val", 2, envir=res)
```

Comment: Edge case: objects passed by reference being modified by reference. `DT = data.table(1); set(get("DT"), j=1L, value=2)`, which works because `get("DT")` is just the pointer to `DT` / essentially is `DT`. Still, don't use `get`, eh.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "hard-code" res, but this works fine... `myfun = function(r, v) r[[ "calls" ]][[ r[["counter"]] ]] <- v; myfun(res, 2)` just extending the answer below. No one has suggested using `$`, I think.

Comment: I'd advise against metaprogramming (putting every object's name into a string), but `myfun((get("res")), 3)` works fine for that if you think you need to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following will address your issue:

`get("calls", envir=res)[[get("counter", envir=res)]] <- 2` fails because `get` is not a [replacement](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html) function. On the other hand `res$calls[[1]] <- 1` is actually a replacement function which you can see if you type `help('[[<-')`. This is the function used when you make an assignment. I think the reason why `get` has no replacement counterpart i.e. (`get<-`) is that there is a specific function to do this, which is called `assign` (as per @TheTime 's comment).

For the second case `val <- get("calls", envir=res)[[get("counter", envir=res)]]` is created in the global environment. When you use `assign("val", 2, envir=res)` a `res$val` variable is created inside the `res` environment which you can see below:

```
> res$val
[1] 2
```

However, `val` remains the same on the global environment as 1:

```
> val
[1] 1
```

So, You probably won't be able to do the assignment with either `get` or `assign`. `get` won't allow it because it is not a replacement function and ?assign mentions:

> assign does not dispatch assignment methods, so it cannot be used to set elements of vectors, names, attributes, etc.

So, you can just use the normal `[[<-` assignment method. @Frank in the comments provides a nice way like:

```
res[[ "calls" ]][[ res[["counter"]] ]] <- 2
```

Comment: @TheTime That's what happens when you have data.table loaded :) . You are absolutely right, thanks,

Comment: You won't be able to do it with either `get` or `assign`. `get` won't allow it because it is not a replacement function and `?assign` mentions: `assign does not dispatch assignment methods, so it cannot be used to set elements of vectors, names, attributes, etc.` Just use the normal `[[<-` assignment method.